# Pagination with the stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to add sorting feature of my pagination stored procedure.

How can I do this, so far I created this one. It works fine but when pass the `@sort` parameter, it didn't work.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Mk]
 @page INT,
 @size INT,
 @sort nvarchar(50) ,
 @totalrow INT  OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @offset INT
    DECLARE @newsize INT

    IF(@page=0)
    begin
       SET @offset = @page;
       SET @newsize = @size
    end
    ELSE 
    begin
        SET @offset = @page+1;
        SET @newsize = @size-1
    end
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    WITH OrderedSet AS
    (
      SELECT *,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @sort DESC) AS 'Index'
      FROM [dbo].[Mk]  
    )
   SELECT * 
   FROM OrderedSet 
   WHERE [Index] BETWEEN @offset AND (@offset + @newsize) 

   SET @totalrow = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Mk])
END
```

Comment: Try `OFFSET FETCH` https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way (possibly not the best) to do it is to use dynamic SQL

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [sp_Mk]
 @page INT,
 @size INT,
 @sort nvarchar(50) ,
 @totalrow INT  OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @offset INT
    DECLARE @newsize INT
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    IF(@page=0)
      BEGIN
        SET @offset = @page
        SET @newsize = @size
       END
    ELSE 
      BEGIN
        SET @offset = @page*@size
        SET @newsize = @size-1
      END
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET @sql = '
     WITH OrderedSet AS
    (
      SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @sort + ') AS ''Index''
      FROM [dbo].[Mk] 
    )
   SELECT * FROM OrderedSet WHERE [Index] BETWEEN ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), @offset) + ' AND ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), (@offset + @newsize)) 
   EXECUTE (@sql)
   SET @totalrow = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Mk])
END
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b4a0/4)** demo

Comment: can I ask you what is the best optimum solution could be

Comment: A better solution is to add pagination using an OFFSET-FETCH clause.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is the devil. It should never be used if there is any viable alternative solution.

Answer (score 21):

I'm adding an answer since so many of the other answers suggest dynamic SQL, which is not a best practice. You can add pagination using an `OFFSET-FETCH` clause, which provides you with an option to fetch only a window or page of results from a result set.

**Note**: `OFFSET-FETCH` can be used only with the `ORDER BY` clause.

Example:

```
SELECT First Name + ' ' + Last Name FROM Employees 
ORDER BY First Name 
OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

If you put it in a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspEmployees_GetAll]  
  @rowOffset int = 0,
  @fetchNextRows int = 100
AS
BEGIN   
    SELECT * FROM Employees     
    ORDER BY ID desc
    OFFSET @rowOffset ROWS FETCH NEXT @fetchNextRows ROWS ONLY;
END
```

You can call it like this

```
DECLARE @rowOffset int
DECLARE @fetchNextRows int


EXECUTE [dbo].[uspEmployees_GetAll] 
   @rowOffset = 0,
   @fetchNextRows = 30
```

Comment: I think it is currently (as of February 2018) the preffered solution, although I should point out that this option is only available since the MS SQL Server Version 2012, see: http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/t-sql-paging-stored-procedure/

Answer (score 8):

```
createprocedure [dbo].[Procedurename]
@Id bigint,
@PageNumber int,
    @PageSize int,
    @Keyword nvarchar(100)
AS
Begin
set NoCount on;

IF(@PageNumber <=0)
    BEGIN
    SET @PageNumber = 1;
    END
    IF(@PageSize<=0)
    BEGIN
    SET @PageSize = 2147483647;
    END
    DECLARE @SkipRows int = (@PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize;


select * from tablename
where ('condition')
and (@Keyword is null or Name like '%'+ @Keyword + '%' or Description like '%'+@Keyword+'%')
order by Id asc 
OFFSET @SkipRows ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
return
End
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming`@sort` is the `column name`. try like this

```
WITH OrderedSet AS
(
 SELECT *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (CASE @sort WHEN 'column_name' 
                                             THEN column_name END ) DESC)  
        AS 'Index'
  FROM [dbo].[Mk] 

 )
```

instead of providing @sort variable put `column name based on @sort`. Hope this will work.

Comment: then? based on what you are doing sorting desc?

Comment: You need to sort based on a column right? `You are passing the name of the column in @sort parameter`. Am I  correct?

Comment: You cant directly convert it(@sort) to column. So you must use `case statement` like above or you need to use `dynamic sql`. Hence the later one seriously affects your performance i suggest the first one.

Comment: getting this error when I do that what u said ,Invalid column name 'column_name'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33952/discussion-between-nithesh-and-user2460637)

Comment: `column_name` which i mentioned there is your sort column name. Provide the name there. Instead of `column_name`. Which all column you may need to sort. I mean possible values of @sort

Comment: it is dynamicaly addded!!?* thats why peterm suggest me dynamic sql

Answer (score 2):

Try using dynamic SQL to fix this.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Mk]
  @page INT,
  @size INT,
  @sort nvarchar(50) ,
  @totalrow INT  OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000)
    DECLARE @Params varchar(200)

SET @Params = N'@page int, @size int, @sort nvarchar(50), @totalrow int OUTPUT'

SET @SQL = '
DECLARE @offset INT
DECLARE @newsize INT

IF(@page=0)
begin
   SET @offset = @page;
   SET @newsize = @size
end
ELSE 
begin
    SET @offset = @page+1;
    SET @newsize = @size-1
end
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
SET NOCOUNT ON;
WITH OrderedSet AS
(
  SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @sort  DESC) AS ''Index''
  FROM [dbo].[Mk]  
)
   SELECT * 
   FROM OrderedSet 
   WHERE [Index] BETWEEN @offset AND (@offset + @newsize) 

   SET @totalrow = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Mk])'


   EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @Params, @page = @page, @size = @size, @sort = @sort, @totalrow = @totalrow 

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.proc_Paging_CTE_Dynamic
(
@Page int,
@RecsPerPage int,
@queryTxt varchar(MAX),
@orderBy varchar(MAX)
)
AS
-- The number of rows affected by the different commands
-- does not interest the application, so turn NOCOUNT ON
SET NOCOUNT ON


DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = '
DECLARE @Page int, @RecsPerPage int
SET @Page = ' + CAST(@Page as varchar) + '
SET @RecsPerPage = ' + CAST(@RecsPerPage as varchar) + '
-- Determine the first record and last record 
DECLARE @FirstRec int, @LastRec int
SELECT @FirstRec = (@Page - 1) * @RecsPerPage
SELECT @LastRec = (@Page * @RecsPerPage + 1);

WITH TempResult as
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ' + @orderBy + ') as RowNum,
  '
  +
  @queryTxt
  +
  '
)
SELECT top (@LastRec-1) *
FROM TempResult
WHERE RowNum > @FirstRec 
AND RowNum < @LastRec
'

EXECUTE (@sql)
-- Turn NOCOUNT back OFF
SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

This way:

```
exec dbo.proc_Paging_CTE_Dynamic 126, 
    15, 
    'SUBSCRIBER.Number, SERVICE_MEMBER.AllowedDays, SERVICE_MEMBER.AllowedUntilTime, SERVICE_MEMBER.AllowedFromTime, SERVICE_MEMBER.Capacity, 
                      SERVICE.Name
        FROM SUBSCRIBER INNER JOIN
                      SERVICE_MEMBER ON SUBSCRIBER.Number = SERVICE_MEMBER.Subscriber_Number INNER JOIN
                      SERVICE ON SERVICE_MEMBER.Service_Id = SERVICE.Id', 
    'Number, Service_Id'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this link and it works pretty well. Does not use string / dynamic sql. 
Instead it uses CASE statement

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN (@lSortCol = ‘ContactID’ AND @SortOrder=‘ASC’)
                    THEN ContactID
        END ASC,
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/590341/Stored-Procedure-with-Sorting-Paging-and-Filtering

Answer (score 0):

the best option is to use CTE, this will have less overhead and doable option
below is a sample that can be useful ,
here we can use the ROW_NUMBER() function to fetch only the relevant rows:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspItemsPaging
(
@Page int,
@RecsPerPage int 

)
AS
-- The number of rows affected by the different commands
-- does not interest the application, so turn NOCOUNT ON
SET NOCOUNT ON


-- Determine the first record and last record 
DECLARE @FirstRec int, @LastRec int

SELECT @FirstRec = (IIF ( @Page > 0 , @Page, 1 ) - 1) * @RecsPerPage - 1) * @RecsPerPage
SELECT @LastRec = (@Page * @RecsPerPage + 1);

WITH TempResult as
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Items.ID DESC) as RowNum,
    Items.*  


     From dbo.Items



)


SELECT top (@LastRec-1) *
FROM TempResult
WHERE RowNum > @FirstRec 
AND RowNum < @LastRec



-- Turn NOCOUNT back OFF
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@qtype varchar(50) = null,
    @page int = 0,
    @limit int = 0

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[post_image_tbl] WHERE u_id IN(SELECT f_id FROM [dbo].[followers_tbl] WHERE u_id = u_id) and
    @limit  BETWEEN ( @page - 1 ) * @limit + 1 AND @page * @limit
     ORDER BY id DESC
```